# Make <input type="file"> height the same as the div container using Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, input, bootstrap-4, height

Second div has the `py-4` tag and only the "Upload" button uses this height. I'd like also this same height for the "Choose file" and "Upload" options. Is this possible just updating the .html file only?

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="custom-file py-4">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="btn input-group-text">Upload</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try and add the class py-4 to the choose file class

Comment: Does not work, see: https://prnt.sc/VL8HGkP7CHn3